# Simple sign in to twitter

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter-oauth

Are there any example how to sign in to twitter in aim to get user id ?

I want to implement sign in to my app using twitter. For that reason i want to get user twitter id.
There are lots of examples how to implement almost all twitter app, but i don't need this.

In twitter documentation there are new sign in way it's called xAuth:
[xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth)

In this there are example of sign in:

```
oauth_consumer_key - JvyS7DO2qd6NNTsXJ4E7zA
oauth_consumer_secret - 9z6157pUbOBqtbm0A0q4r29Y2EYzIHlUwbF4Cl9c
oauth_nonce - 6AN2dKRzxyGhmIXUKSmp1JcB4pckM8rD3frKMTmVAo
oauth_signature_method - HMAC-SHA1
oauth_timestamp - 1284565601
oauth_version - 1.0
x_auth_mode - client_auth
x_auth_password - twitter-xauth
x_auth_username - oauth_test_exec
```

I don't get, how to retrieve   `oauth_consumer_key`, `oauth_consumer_secret`, `oauth_nonce`

Maybe there are example of simple sign in using OAuth ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try check this example [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) And if will not help, then this [list](https://github.com/search?q=twitter%20auth&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Everything&language=Objective-C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Consumer Key & Consumer Secret, you have to create an app in Twitter via [this](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) link.

Then you'll be taking to page containing Consumer Key & Consumer Secret

U can use [sharekit](http://getsharekit.com/) for authentication in twitter just provide your apps Consumer Key & Consumer Secret in it

Comment: Can i sign in to twitter with my app  without creating an app in twitter ?

Comment: your r creating means registering your app to get request of using twitter api on your application.

Comment: I mean i just want to send twitter user login and pasword and get it id. Just this

Comment: then also u will need these keys to access Twitter API